# How to check if a user is at a specific region

Tags: swift, core-location

I'm wondering the easiest way to check and see if a user's current location is in range of a specific region. I have the region I want and I have the users current location all set up. I just need to know how to compare them. I tried using

```
startMonitoringForRegion
```

but that did not work because I have an MKCoordinateRegion

does anyone have a solution?
Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the region to MKMapRect and the coordinate to MKMapPoint and call `MKMapRectContainsPoint`.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/index.html